# Trying to pass a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Hey new to java currently am stuck and do not know what i am doing wrong, i am making a simple code that is that works like a social media platform, to make a profile i need to include(name,image,friends,status), i keep getting an error at "BufferedImage@9304b1" in my driver class - Thank you Boann

Now i run and receive a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.(Unknown Source)"

```
package Social;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Profile {

static BufferedImage profilePicture;  //store image
ArrayList<Profile> friends; //store a list of friends
String name;
String status;

public Profile() {
    profilePicture = null;
    friends = null;
    name = null;
    status = null;
}


public Profile(String name, String profilePictureName, String status) throws Exception {
    this.name = name;
    try {
        this.profilePicture = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File(profilePictureName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    this.status = status;
}

public ArrayList<Profile> getFriends(){
    return friends;

}
public static BufferedImage read(File input)throws IOException{
    return null;


}
}


public class Driver {

public Driver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Profile JohnDoe = new Profile(); 
    JohnDoe("John Doe","BufferedImage@9304b1","My name is John.");


    }

    }
```

Comment: "BufferedImage@9304b1" isn't meaningful code. What do you want it to do?

Comment: @Boann i am trying to create a new Profile but when i try to add my Picture i get a "BufferedImage cannot be resolved to a variable
 Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Comment: What picture? Where? Are you trying to load one from a file? Draw one from scratch using graphics commands?

Comment: im trying to load one from file

Comment: "BufferedImage@9304b1" is a transient debugging id produced by BufferedImage's toString method. It can suggest whether two images references share a memory allocation, but it can not be used to identify an image, to reference an image or to load an image. To load an image from a file in Java, search for "load an image from a file in java"

Comment: i need to store that BufferedImage a part of this Profile

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you call the constructor:

```
Profile JohnDoe = new Profile(); 
JohnDoe(....);
```

When you do `new Profile()`, that constructs the object and calls its no-arg constructor, and you can only call a constructor for each object once (when you construct it!), so the following line is invalid. So join those lines together:

```
Profile JohnDoe = new Profile(....);
```

Filling in the parameters, including a String path to a profile picture, you get:

```
Profile JohnDoe = new Profile("John Doe", "path/to/your-profile-picture.jpg", "My name is John.");
```

I suggest you ditch the `ArrayList<Profile> friends` parameter from the constructor. It's not useful as you would have a chicken and egg problem trying to supply constructed `Profile` objects to each other's constructors.

One way to solve that would be to initialize the friends field directly with a blank list:

```
private final ArrayList<Profile> friends = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then set up the contents of the `Profile` objects' friends lists after the `Profile` objects are otherwise constructed.

And/or, give each profile a unique ID (e.g., an arbitrary number or a fixed name), and store friends as a list of profile IDs rather than a list of `Profile` objects. You can separately have a `Map` for retrieving `Profile` objects from profile IDs.

You can remove the no-arg constructor from the `Profile` class as it is not now being used, and in any case it does not set any of the fields to useful valid values.

In the remaining constructor, you should fix the parameter names to conform to the convention that variables should start with a lowercase letter. You can qualify access to the object's fields with `this.` to distinguish them from the same-named parameters.

To your actual question, to load an image from a file as a `BufferedImage` object, call [`javax.imageio.ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-) with the `File` object. To deal with the [catch or specify requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) imposed by the file loading operation, wrap it in some try-catch block (or declare the constructor with `throws IOException`). Thus your `Profile` constructor would become:

```
public Profile(String name, String profilePictureName, String status) {
    this.name = name;
    try {
        this.profilePicture = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File(profilePictureName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
    this.status = status;
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

Okay, your new posted code clearly doesn't throw the exception you say it does, because it doesn't compile at all, but anyway.

First, fix the constructor invocation in `main` in the way I explained before.

The no-arg constructors of the `Profile` and `Driver` classes are both doing nothing and can be removed.

Remove the `read` method.

You don't want the `profilePicture` field to be `static`.

If you used `throw new Exception(e)` instead of `throw new UncheckedIOException(e)` only because you are using an older version of Java that doesn't have that class, then change it to `throw new RuntimeException(e)` instead. The idea of using an unchecked exception type like that was to avoid the need to declare `throws IOException` on the constructor and its callers, which makes things easier in the end. But if you'd prefer to declare `throws IOException` on the constructor (or `throws Exception`, as you are currently) then you can instead remove the try/catch/throw lines around the image loading call. The point is, you don't need to both declare *and* catch & re-throw.

Your main problem is that `"BufferedImage@9304b1"` is not the name of a file. (Well I suppose it *could* be, but it probably isn't, unless you deliberately renamed the file to remove the '.jpg' or '.png' or whatever its extension was.) Use the path and name of some file that is on your computer.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!! I have continued to add the code and now am stuck again.